# Matlab source control with Git 'Method not implemented.' errors

Tags: git, matlab, curl, github, version-control

Yesterday I set up source control in Matlab using Git following the guide [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2014/10/20/matlab-and-git/) at the mathworks blog. It seemed to work and I was able to connect to my remote repo.

I can commit changes to my local repo but today when I try to push or fetch to the remote repo, by **Source Control > Push** or **Source Control > Fetch** I get an error dialog saying

> Method not implemented.

I tried running the command `!git fetch` from the Matlab command line and got

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/USER/REPO.git/': Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl

From reading, I've discovered this is because the curl packaged with matlab does not support https, however my system curl does so I just created an alias to the system curl in the Matlab folder, and the `!git fetch` command now works.

But trying to push / fetch through the UI still does not...

I am also at the moment unable to setup source control in other folders as when trying to Validate a Path to a Git Repository I get

> Invalid path: https://github.com/Azureuse/Photon-Pistol.git
>
> Method not implemented.

But this did work yesterday...

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? It appears to me that something is flakey in the implementation of git in matlab.

I'm running Matlab 2015a on OSX Yosemite.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You might getter better results asking this on the [MathWorks forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/) or by [filing a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us/?s_tid=gn_cntus).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm encountering the same problem.